# Mdf painted without being primed

Tags: painting, paint, primer, mdf

I put up MDF panels on my wall.

The painter didn’t use primer and directly painted with paint.

Can i go over with primer and then repaint? Are there any other solutions

Comment: How big of an area are you talking about? Can you post a picture? What kind of topcoat was used?

Comment: Is there a current problem you are trying to solve? Is there something wrong with the appearance of the MDF right now?

Answer (score 1):

I don't anticipate a problem. Both water and oil based paints should bond to MDF. The main advantage of primer on that surface would actually be to seal it so the water or oil in the main paint doesn't soak in so strongly and potentially cause swelling.

If it looks good now, I think you're fine.

Answer (score 0):

Directly painting anything without primer is a bad idea. Primer is like a glue between the surface and the paint.

Some paints come with primer as part of the paint. If you can see the cans the painter used, and they say "Primer/Paint", then the primer is part of the paint. (I don't know how well combination primer/paint works in comparison with separate primer and paint applications.)

If the paint used by the painter is straight paint without primer, then the painter goofed. The paint may peel off over time. Painting over it may only cause your new paint to peel off with the painter's paint, or your new paint may pull more when drying and start the peeling process quicker.

Asking the painter whether there was primer in the paint may or may not not get you reliable information. Myself, unless I saw the actual cans used, I would insist on a fix, or I'd dispute the work with my payment method company or bank.

Comment: It is the standard dulux matt paint. It does mot have primer. And i cannot dispute or insist on a fix. Here is the paint: https://www.diy.com/departments/dulux-walls-ceilings-tranquil-dawn-matt-emulsion-paint-2-5l/5010212650042_BQ.prd?storeId=2904&gad_source=1&gbraid=0AAAAADt-XHnbSff-NRvczwAX3oLDXn81-&gclsrc=ds

Comment: Is it possible to go over with the primer and then repaint or do you recommend another option without removing the panels

Comment: Going over the paint with something else is addressed above:  "The paint may peel off over time. Painting over it may......"  You certainly can paint over it, nothing will stop you. Whether it will stay or peel off only time will tell. Why you can't dispute may be a good subject for a new question, perhaps on the Legal SE. You may have more options than you think. Unless the painter was you or your kids, etc. :)